Is this a redirect or not?
I see the following page behavior:
After clicking on a ahref link /product-1, a page with url product-1 loads, and, after few seconds, the url changes to product-1?param=1.
This is definitely not a meta equiv redirects. It happens with a javascript, and there is no status code change - the status code remains 200, and my DevTools Network tab doesn't display the url switch from non-param to param version.
Should I consider this behavior as a redirect or not?

From the sounds of that behaviour, no, that's not a redirect. You can append URL parameters to the current URL using JS, without redirecting/reloading the page

DevTools Network tab doesn't display the url switch - nothing in devtools network (and it's not filtered...) then no network activity -> not a page redirect

This would not be a traditional redirect, because.

There is no HTTP status change.
The addition of a param to the url is probably via JS
There are no redirects in the network so it is only client side.

It is more of a client side url manipulation and probably done with something like history.pushState() or replaceState
